# How to send command from coordinator to router in Xbee?

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I am using an XBee-PRO S2b module. I have sent data from the router Xbee to the coordinator Xbee.

Now I want to send a command packet from the coordinator to the router Xbee to set a pin high.

My coordinator is in API mode and the router is in AT mode.

Can anyone say how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the router from the coordinator, you have to create a function that run in a microcontroller that is connected to the coordinator.You can refer to this link , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzH146rR-7I&t=236s

Comment: it is using xbee s2 but i think it works under the same protocol.